# Loading service for IIS securely

Tags: c#, iis, servicestack, sandbox, lxc

I want to develop PaaS like for IIS, I want users to be able to upload dll and I will host them. Those dll's will be ServiceStack services.

I want to sandbox those apis, so they can access the internet - only to certain ip's , but to limit their OS access for file system - Only for some directory that have max limit of 20mb (for example).

I know that in linux I have containers like docker that can help me do that easily, any Ideas how to do this in .NET (open source libraries for helping are more than welcomed :))

Answer (score 1):

You could use Code Access Security and Trust levels for that.

Take a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y(v=vs.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87x8e4d1(v=vs.100).aspx